# How to start Windows with a Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7, startup

is there any solution to start a Windows PC with a Python program at a certain time?
I can't find any answer but I heard of a program with this function, but the thing is that i want to program mine myself.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean by "start with a Python script". You can configure a program to run _after_ Windows has started up, and that program can be a Python script. See [How to Add Programs, Files, and Folders to System Startup in Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/208224/how-to-add-programs-files-and-folders-to-system-startup-in-windows-8.1/).

Answer (score 1):

No. Python runs within your operating system, so it can't run when your computer is turned off (barring a really odd BMC or something). The normal way of doing this is by configuring it in your BIOS/UEFI settings.